# How to launch Twitter app from Tweet URL in Reminders in iOS 11

Tags: reminders, twitter, ios

I am using 6th gen iPod touch.
When I was using iOS 10.3, Tweet URLs in Reminders showed with Twitter icons, and I could open Twitter app from Reminders by tapping Tweet URLs.
From when I updated to iOS 11, Tweet URLs in Reminders showed without icons, and I could not open neither Twitter app nor Safari from Reminders by tapping Tweet URLs.

How can I launch Twitter app with tap Tweet URL in Reminders in iOS 11 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal link from Reminder app is now re-activated on iOS 11.2 and Twitter 7.12.1.